# dataframe index resets when creating smaller dataframe

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

PIP install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery  fails!! i have no idea what to do!

I have upgraded PIP but still no respite

```
MacBook-Pro-4:~ riyer$ pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
Collecting google-cloud-bigquery

   awscli 1.10.58 has requirement botocore==1.4.48, but you'll have botocore 1.6.5 which is incompatible.
    Installing collected packages: setuptools, protobuf, googleapis-common-protos, google-api-core, google-cloud-core, google-cloud-bigquery
      Found existing installation: setuptools 20.3
Cannot remove entries from nonexistent file /Users/riyer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth
```

Comment: As the error message says - you've got incompatible version of `botocore` installed (needs `1.4.48` but you've got `1.6.5`).

Comment: can you please tell me how i can "downgrade" or install a second version of botocore

Comment: Quickl googling shows: `pip install --user install botocore==1.4.48`. Maybe give that a try.

Comment: @user8652079 To downgrade `botocore`, you can try first to uninstall botocore using `pip uninstall botocore` and then install the lower version using `pip install botocore==1.4.48`.